# automatic randomly change image view image from an array contain of image [swift]

Tags: swift, xcode

I am trying to **change and show image to Image View Randomly with few second delay** from an **array** contain of images.

But When I press button action all code execute well what I want but **I do not see real time change image automatically one by one** in the simulator just show last random image

### here is my code

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageViewTop: UIImageView!

let myArray = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "A"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "B"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "C"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "D")]

@IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        for i in 0..<myArray.count {
            print("Process start \(i)")
            
            imageViewTop.image = myArray.randomElement()
            
            print(myArray.randomElement()!)
            sleep(5)
            print("Process End \(i)")
        }
    }
```

### Here is my Console output

I see my Console output **print statement** delay with 5 second that's work fine. but not see changing image in my image-view into the simulator one by one

> Process start 0
>
> <UIImage:0x600000131050 named(main: B) {341, 341}>
>
> Process End 0
>
> Process start 1
>
> <UIImage:0x600000131170 named(main: C) {341, 341}>
>
> Process End 1
>
> Process start 2
>
> <UIImage:0x600000131050 named(main: A) {341, 341}>
>
> Process End 2
>
> Process start 3
>
> <UIImage:0x600000131050 named(main: C) {341, 341}>
>
> Process End 3

[image: Xcode Editor ScreenShot]

Comment: You don't need the `for-loop` and you shouldn't be using `sleep` in the main thread.  You'd want to try and look at `Timer` instead

Comment: your idea is working #MadProgrammer but I need to use loop with do this is it possible?

Comment: Why?  Use the `Timer` as a pseudo loop

Comment: If I was doing something like this, I would randomise the list, copy it to a second list and each time the `Timer` ticked, pop off the first element, this way you wouldn't get any image repeating.  When the list was empty you could the stop the `Timer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instant of use **for** loop and **sleep()** I use Timer then it's work fine

```
@IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { timer in
            
        self.imageViewTop.image = self.myArray.randomElement()

//        if [condition] {
//            timer.invalidate() // Stop the repeats when condition match
//        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you want sequential image change in your logic.

You can use Timer() to change your image after a specific time interval.

Check the below code for Image change with the help of Timer().

**Step1:**

```
//Create a Timer object.
var changeImageTimer: Timer?
```

**Step2:**

```
//Run your timer either from ViewDidLoad or on button click action.

@IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    
    //Check timer running or not
    if let timer = changeImageTimer, timer.isValid {
        changeImageTimer?.invalidate()
    }
    
    //Change Image Randomly
//        changeImageTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self, selector: #selector(changeImageRandomly), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    
    //Change Image in sequence
    index = 0
    changeImageTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2, target: self, selector: #selector(changeImageInSequence), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

**Step3:**

```
//Timer function where you can put your image change logic this method calls after a time interval.
@objc func changeImageRandomly() {
    //Rendom Pick from array
    print("Image changes randomly.")
    imageViewTop.image = myArray.randomElement()
}

@objc func changeImageInSequence() {
    print("Image Change in Sequence with Index = ",index)
    if index < myArray.count {
        //Seq Pick from array
        imageViewTop.image = myArray[index]
        index += 1
    } else {
        changeImageTimer?.invalidate()
    }
}
```

So on 3rd step, you have 2 options you can change the image randomly or in sequence by using **index** variable which will increment on every call and change the image.

Check this GIF:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUVCx.jpg

Hope this will help you to get an image update at a specific time interval.